# How to wait for user action in separate Modal before continuing function execution?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm developing a drink counter app. User can add drinks but also has a drinkLimit state that is used to remind the user if the limit is reached when adding drinks. This reminder pops up in a modal with cancel and continue buttons when drink count has reached it's limit. The user can then either cancel the new drink addition or continue with it.

**The problem is that I need to somehow wait or check for the user's action (clicking either "cancel" or "continue" in the modal), and based on that either return out of the addDrink function or continue the addition.** I'm not sure how to implement that.

Using `async/await` seems intuitive but how can I await for a function when that function runs only after user clicks a button?

Using callbacks might be another solution but there as well I would need to halt the execution until user makes his action.

This seems like a common use case but I still can't seem to find any questions or tuts about this specific case.

App.tsx

```
const App = () => {
  const [drinklist, setDrinkList] = useState<DrinkType[]>();
  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState<FavDrinkType[] | null>(null);
  const [drinkLimit, setDrinkLimit] = useState<number>();
  const [actionCalled, setActionCalled] = useState<string | null>();

const addDrink = (alcPercent: number, amount: number, name?: string) => {

    // if drink limit has been reached open reminder modal
    if (drinkLimit && drinklist) {
      if (drinklist?.length >= drinkLimit) {

        // how do I pause the execution here?
        const action = await openReminder();

        //cancel add
        if (action === 'cancel') {
          setShowReminder(false);
          return
        }
      }
    }
    
    // continue add
    
    setShowReminder(false);

    // *addition logic* (irrelevant)
  };

// Opens the modal (and waits for the user's action?)
const openReminder = async () => {
    setShowReminder(true);

  // should I wait for function handleActionCalled()?
}

// Modal calls this and sets state
const handleActionCalled = async (action: string) => {
    setActionCalled(action);
}

return (
      <View>
        <ReminderModal
          showModal={showReminder}
          handleActionCalled={handleActionCalled}
        />
      </View>
```

ReminderModal.tsx:

```
const ReminderModal = ({
  showModal,
  handleActionCalled,
}: ReminderModalProps) => {

  const handleAction = (action: string) => {
    switch (action) {
      case 'cancel':
        return handleActionCalled('cancel');
      case 'continue':
        return handleActionCalled('continue');
    }
  };
  return (
    <Modal visible={showModal} animationType="slide" transparent={true}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAction('cancel')}>
              <View>
                <Text>Cancel</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handleAction('continue')}>
              <View>
                <Text>Continue</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    </Modal>
```

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-modal-component - I Googled this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are overcomplicating the issue, you should break down your flow in multiple steps:

1. On first action => open modal if the addDrinks estimate that it reaches the limit. Should be the end of this function
2. a/ if hit cancel => trigger a
   function that closes the modal

   b/if hit continue trigger the
   addDrinks function

I don't think you should include the opening of the modal as part of your addDrink function, or it should trigger a new flow but not await for an answer here.